# Memcpy data directly into std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, memcpy

Is it legal to directly copy data into the underlying buffer of a std::vector using memcpy? Something like this:

```
char buf[255];
FillBuff(buf);

std::vector<char> vbuf;
vbuf.resize(255);

memcpy(vbuf.data(), &buf, 255);
```

Comment: Fine with a simple [POD type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) like `char`. Don't try it with, for example, a `std::vector<std::string>`. Side note: Worth seeing if you can `FillBuff(vbuf.data());` and skip the `memcpy` entirely.

Comment: Note also that `memcpy(vbuf.data(), &buf, 255);` has an unneeded `&`; just `memcpy(vbuf.data(), buf, 255);` will do.

Comment: Yes but why, just use `std::copy`

Comment: @M.A It may be required, for example, to pass the `vbuf.data()` pointer to a function (maybe written in plain ol' C) that takes a `char*` argument.

Comment: Yes, it ok, but use `std::copy(std::begin(buf), std::end(buf), vbuf.begin());` - The assembly will most probably be the same but it makes for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question yes, it does work **but** that is due to the implementation of `std::vector<char>`.

For non-POD types and types for which `std::vector` has a particular template specialisation that affects the memory layout (`std::vector<bool>`), it will not work. This is why you should use `std::copy`, it will behave correctly irrespective.

As noted by @user4581301, `memcpy` may be unnecessary as you can treat `std::vector:: data()` as you do the `char* buffer`.